# printing unchanged string in JS

Tags: javascript, string

In C# I can do the following:

```
String1 = "Test \r\n test!";
String2 = @"Test \r\n test!";
```

output String1:

```
Test
 test!
```

output String2:

```
Test \r\n test!
```

In JavaScript I only found `unescape()`. But that is completly outdated and is not really what I was searching for, because that translated special characters to other things. I want that 'nothing' is translated, but everything is given out as it was in the string. Has someone an idea how I can do in JS what I can achieve in C# with the '@'?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will effectively do what you want, or at least something pretty close to what you want. It'll encode things for the purpose of JSON syntax of course, but as I say that's close to what you describe.

Comment: And yes `unescape()` is definitely not the tool for the job; it's for URL syntax.

Comment: @Cid you're seeing the behavior of the console.  Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(whatever))`

Comment: @Pointy haha yes right my bad

Comment: @Pointy —- It won't if the input is `"\ "`. Escape sequences would be normalised by the initial parse.

Comment: @Quentin yes, I realize that; that's why I qualified the recommendation. There's no way to retrieve the original "useless" escapes from the source string of course.

Comment: Hm, ok. So I have two choices? Changing the string in advance, so that EVERY (even there are millions) backslash is changed to a double backslash OR I have work with the JSON variant where I have to deal with some extra " ? Hm, thanks. Not what I hoped for, but it is at least a hint.

Comment: @MarcelGrüger it's basically just not a feature of the language. The pre-parse string constant text is not maintained anywhere at run time.

Comment: @MarcelGrüger  How have you managed to end up with JavaScript source code containing millions of incorrect string literals in the first place?

Comment: Its meant for reading data from a database and that could be huge when it is some years in action.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a database for your data and not JS source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has no equivalent to C# verbatim string literals.

You need to escape special characters when creating the string.

```
const string1 = "Test \\r\\n test!";
```

---

Some people have suggested using `JSON.stringify`, but the initial parsing of the string will normalise it, so you can't reliably recover the original input.

For example, an escaped space means the same as a space on its own.

```js
const input = "A string containing a \ character";
const output = JSON.stringify(input);
document.write(output);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer was downvoted

Comment: I am pretty sure initially it was because some people thought the comment about stringify answered it - now there are more to it than that